# Facebook FQL: using special characters when searching by friends name

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm using FQL to search for friends. This is one example that works:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND strpos(lower(name),'hugo') >=0
```

Now, I want to make a search that returns all friends containing "anto":
Example names (notice the special character: ó):
"antónio manuel"
"antonieta maria"

How can I achieve this? Is there any replace function in FQL?

Note: I don't want to use something like: 
    (...) AND (strpos(lower(name),'anto') >=0 OR strpos(lower(name),'antó') >=0)

thank you

Comment: Yeah, I had to go with the "OR" option:
http://hastebin.com/sivefawafu.php (CakePHP 2)

Comment: @davidmh,  I don't want to use "OR" option because there's a lot of possible combinations:  example: if the user search for "antonio maria" you must explode this to:  ántonio maria  or antónio maria  or antonío maria  or antonió maria  or antonio mária  (...)  or ántónio maria  or antónió maria  (...)  or ântonio maria  or antônio maria  (...)...  There's to many combinations to be sure that you will be querying the database for all the options.  Does your function create all these combinations?

Comment: That's what `query_variations` does, here is the FQL query for "antonio maria": http://hastebin.com/lusakeraqi.sql

I splited the words to reduce the variations, the search it's a bit broader, but in my case works like a charm.

Comment: updated function and fql output:

http://hastebin.com/qegevaloki.php
http://hastebin.com/cipojegigo.sql 

Removed ñ cause facebook ignores it anyway and narrowed the search to name instead of first_name and last_name

Comment: @davidmh, I think that this is not the solution I'm looking for... let me try to explain: http://hastebin.com/gotuqekihi.vhdl